# AngularJS: Two entrypoints for one (similar) app?

Tags: angularjs

I want to distribute my app in two similar variants. Only the start screen of both variants is different.

What's the right pattern for this setup? I think using a index_a.html and index_b.html is a good start?!

My index.html looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>myApp</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/application.css"/>

</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/directives.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mind elaborating what a 'starscreen' is? Did you mean start screen?

Comment: sry, the start screen (= homepage)